# Python equivalent of PHP's compact() and extract()

Tags: php, python, dictionary

[compact](http://www.php.net/compact)() and [extract](http://www.php.net/extract)() are functions in PHP I find tremendously handy.  compact() takes a list of names in the symbol table and creates a hashtable with just their values.  extract does the opposite.  e.g.,

```
$foo = 'what';
$bar = 'ever';
$a = compact('foo', 'bar');
$a['foo']
# what
$a['baz'] = 'another'
extract(a)
$baz
# another
```

Is there a way to do the same in Python?  I've looked all around and the closest I've come is [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/r52hym6zfy7hd2ch), which seems to frown on it.

I know about locals(), globals() and vars(), but how can I handily select just a subset of their values?

Does Python have something even better that obviates the need for this?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what was confusing me.  It looks like your line 3 should be "$a = compact('foo', 'bar');" instead.

Comment: oops, thanks. I just corrected it.

Comment: Can I ask why you find them handy? I don't see what they are good for that couldn't be more cleanly implemented using hashtables.

Comment: hashtables may be cleaner semantically and arguably less error prone, but the above I find cleaner to read and write.

thanks for all the answers!

Comment: This would seem to be useful in python when running tests, since unless I'm mistaken there's no way to provide a context dictionary to timeit.Timer.  eg `context = {c.a:1, c.b:2}; timeit.Timer('c.a+c.b', 'import __main__.context as c')` would become a bit more straightforward if `a` and `b` could be extracted into the test context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not very Pythonic, but if you really must, you can implement `compact()` like this:

```
import inspect

def compact(*names):
    caller = inspect.stack()[1][0] # caller of compact()
    vars = {}
    for n in names:
        if n in caller.f_locals:
            vars[n] = caller.f_locals[n]
        elif n in caller.f_globals:
            vars[n] = caller.f_globals[n]
    return vars
```

It used to be possible to implement `extract()` like this, but in modern Python interpreters this doesn't appear to work anymore (not that it was ever "supposed" to work, really, but there were quirks of the implementation in 2009 that let you get away with it):

```
def extract(vars):
    caller = inspect.stack()[1][0] # caller of extract()
    for n, v in vars.items():
        caller.f_locals[n] = v   # NEVER DO THIS - not guaranteed to work
```

If you really feel you have a need to use these functions, you're probably doing something the wrong way. It seems to run against [Python's philosophy](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) on at least three counts: "explicit is better than implicit", "simple is better than complex", "if the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea", maybe more (and really, if you have enough experience in Python you know that stuff like this just isn't done). I could see it being useful for a debugger or post-mortem analysis, or perhaps for some sort of *very general* framework that frequently needs to create variables with dynamically chosen names and values, but it's a stretch.

Comment: I have a logging usecase, sometimes I need to collect x number of variables and log them with compact instead of repeating myself doing {a:a, b:b, c:c}, I remember there was a language were you could say {a, b, c} and would automatically create the dictionary with the values, can't remember which.

Answer (score 10):

I'm afraid there are no equivalents in Python. To some extent, you can simulate their effect using (and passing) `locals`:

```
>>> def compact(locals, *keys):
...     return dict((k, locals[k]) for k in keys)
...
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 2
>>> compact(locals(), 'a', 'b')
{'a': 10, 'b': 2}

>>> def extract(locals, d):
...     for k, v in d.items():
...         locals[k] = v
...
>>> extract(locals(), {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
>>> a
'foo'
>>> b
'bar'
```

Nevertheless, I don't think these functions are "tremendously handy". Dynamic global/local variables are evil and error-prone -- PHP guys learned that when they discouraged register_globals.  From my experience, few experienced PHP programmers or major frameworks use `compact()` or `extract()`.

In Python, [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
a = 1
b = 2
# compact
c = dict(a=a, b=b)

# extract
a, b = d['a'], d['b']
```

Comment: I'm all for explicit, but why must it be redundant?

wouldn't this be less error-prone?

c = compact(a, b)

Answer (score 9):

Is it worth pointing out that `extract()` (and to a lesser extent, `compact()`) is one of the most "evil" features of PHP (along with `register_globals` and `eval`), and should be avoided?

[`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) makes it much harder to determine where a variable was defined.  When it is harder to trace a variable back to where it was defined, it's harder to check for common security problems like using uninitialized variables, or unfiltered variables which originated from user input.

[`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) is not as bad, but if used badly can still make it more difficult than it would otherwise be to see where an array member gets set from a variable.

The equivalent of `extract()` in many other languages is the `with` keyword.  Python now has a `with` keyword, though it works a bit differently, making it not quite like `extract()`.  However, in other languages such as Javascript, the `with` keyword [also has a poor reputation](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

I think the best advice would be to think differently - instead of trying to emulate a bad feature of PHP, think of other ways to do what you want to do with concise and readable code.

Comment: Please note that the 'with' statement in Python has completely different semantics than in JavaScript and does not change any "variable scope". Also it is a pretty new feature and certainly has no poor reputation. You are right with the JavaScript-"with", though.

Comment: I edited it to the point of no longer making sense because it doesn’t fit in one comment, but all of it is important. I didn’t roll it back afterwards because it was converted to a comment. I deleted it because I felt it didn’t answer the question, because, as it’s written in the first sentence of your comment, you’re just pointing something out.

Comment: Well with 8 upvotes and no downvotes it certainly seems like some people thought it deserved to be here???

Comment: Sometimes the best answers to a question don't answer the question literally, but point out a problem in the entire approach serving as the premise to the question.  That's how I justify this answer being here.

Comment: using "compact" as a really compact way to assemble a kind of dictionary for passing it into a view from the particular controller/action (MVC) is a very easy way to do that and it is a common practice in certain leading PHP Frameworks (Symfony), so do not see anything wrong in using it for proper purposes

Comment: @Zippp It's certainly not as bad as extract, so maybe it doesn't belong in same category.  Its only downside is that it potentially makes it a little more difficult to see where an array member gets set from a variable, though code readability will always depend on other aspects of your coding style too.  I'm willing to soften my views on compact() a little.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's compact function in Python (works with 2.6; not guaranteed to work with earlier versions of Python):

```
import inspect
def compact(*args):
    return dict([(i, inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.get(i, None)) 
                  for i in args])
```

I've written more extensively about this: [Python can be just as ugly as PHP](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2009/05/14/python-can-be-just-as-ugly-as-php/).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the equivalent of `extract($x)` is `globals().update(x)`, as for `compact()` it's a subset of `vars()`

```
>>> foo, bar, baz = 1, 2, 3
# extract
>>> globals().update({"foo": 4, "qux": 5})
>>> foo
4
>>> qux
5
# compact
>>> d = dict((k, v) for k, v in vars().iteritems() if k in ["foo", "bar"])
>>> d
{'bar': 2, 'foo': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this (though I would suggest only sparingly...) with the `locals()` function, which returns an updatable `dict`.  Example:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
>>> locals().update({'derek':'anderson'})
>>> derek
'anderson'
>>>
```

So `locals()` would be "compact all" and `locals().update()` would be `extract`.

Best of luck!

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)  clearly says "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified".