# Have a keyword parser function return variables into local namespace

Tags: python

This may be a straight-up unwise idea so I'd best explain the context. I am finding that some of my functions have multiple and sometimes mutually exclusive or interdependent keyword arguments - ie, they offer the user the ability to input a certain piece of data as (say) a numpy array or a dataframe. And then if a numpy array, an index can be separately passed, but not if it it's a dataframe.

Which has led me to wonder if it's worth creating some kind of keyword parser function to handle these exclusivities/dependencies. One issue with this is that the keyword parser function would then need to return any variables created (and ex-ante, we would not know their number or their names) into the namespace of the function that called it. I'm not sure if that's possible, at least in a reasonable way (I imagine it could be achieved by directly changing the local dict but that's sometimes said to be a bad idea).

So my question is:
1. Is this a bad idea in the first place? Would creating separate functions depending on whether the input was a dataframe or ndarray be more sensible and simpler?
2. Is it possible without too much hacking to have a function return an unspecified number of variables into the local namespace?

Apologies for the slightly vague nature of this question but any thoughts gratefully received.

Comment: Here's [an answer I posted once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783867/56541) that might be related.

Comment: Why not package the results of the parse into a dice, or even an instance of a class designed to hold those results?  It avoids hacking the local namespace, and could include the parser function (for neatness) too.

Comment: @DavidZ, thanks and yes that is kind of similar. One of the responses puts it best when it says that the reason it's discouraged is because it's not obvious to a third party where the variables are coming from. I get that and it seems like it's worth bearing that in mind.

Comment: @cco Yes - I think that might be the way to go, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @cco I agree, and that comment (or something like it) would probably make a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dict is a good way to package a variable number of named values.  If the parser returns a dict, then there is a single object that can be queried to get those names and values, avoiding the problem of needing to know the number and names ahead of time.
Another possibility would be to put the parser into a class, either as a factory method (classmethod or staticmethod returning an instance) or as a regular method (invoked during or after `__init__`), where the class instance holds the parsed values.