# Fastest way to add many parameters with their names as keys to a dict programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

During many projects, I find myself very frequently assigning variables to a dict, where the name of the variable is the key and the variable's value is the value in the dict. For instance:

```
def create_results_dict(age, sex, ...):
    res = {}
    res['age'] = age
    res['sex'] = sex
    ...
    return res
```

I'm wondering what would be a pythonic and efficient (in terms of execution speed) way to doing these assignments dynamically/programmatically? I.e., so that one does not have to write all the assignments manually (lines 3-5, in my example).

Edit: The parameters are just one or more positional or named parameters, i.e., a variable that has a name and a value. I guess, fundamentally the question is, can I receive programmatically the name of a parameter/variable (from a list of parameters passed to a function)?

Comment: well... I suppose you could do: `def create_result_dict(**kwargs): return kwargs` and then use it as `d = create_results_dict(age=5, sex='M', name='Bob')` or something, but then you might as well just use `d = dict(age=5, sex='M', name='Bob')` or similar...?

Comment: Regarding the edit... does using `**kwargs` not fulfil that or are are you determined to only use positional arguments here? It's doable with some hackery but unpacking keyword-arguments is already builtin and efficient as it's part of the argument passing machinery in Python.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783781/python-equivalent-of-phps-compact-and-extract/783867#783867

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Method using [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

```
def create_results(age, sex, marital_status = "single"):
    return {k:v for k, v in locals().items() if not k.startswith('__')}

res = create_results(34, "male")

print(res)
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'marital_status': 'single', 'sex': 'male', 'age': 34}
```

Comment: The `if not k.startswith('__')` check is a nice touch because that filters out the `__class__` cell in methods that use `super()`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey--thanks, since I was debating if it was needed before your tip.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def create_results_dic(age, sex, time, name, country):
    args = create_results_dic.__code__.co_argcount
    items = create_results_dic.__code__.co_varnames
    res = {}
    for x in items[:args]:
        res[x] = eval(x)
    return res
```

If you don't mind using the horribly insecure `eval()`, this is one solution. It iterates through the first `args` variables in the scope, where `args` is the number of args passed to the function. It uses each arg as the name of a key, and gets the value of that variable using `eval`.

This does of course assume all your args passed are to be added to the dict.

Comment: This looks like a very bad way of writing `res = dict(locals())`.