# Any way to shorten dict(a=a)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a long list of long variable names that I need to pack into a dictionary - so my code can end up looking like this:

```py
configs = dict(
    long_variable_name_1=long_variable_name_1,
    not_longest_variable_name_3=not_longest_variable_name_3,
    longer_variable_name_2=longer_variable_name_2,
    # ...
)
```

Instead of saying "this equals this", can we make a function `magic_fn` that takes just "this" and returns `dict(this=this)`? i.e. `magic_fn(a, b) == dict(a=a, b=b)`

From an information standpoint, `dict(a=a)` involves a redundancy, since `magic_fn` can take just one `a` and do the `a=a` internally. I understand this isn't how a Python dict works, and that left `a` is a key, etc. - but maybe there's some trickery to be exploited from builtins and metafunctions.

---

**Update**: none of the answers in other questions accomplish what I seek, nor ask exactly what I ask; my goal is to shorten the `stuff=stuff` syntax with local variables *in-scope* - no user input, etc.

---

**My answer**:

```py
def to_dict(var_str):
    while " " in var_str:  # trim all spaces
        var_str = var_str.replace(" ", "")
    return {name:eval("%s" % name) for name in var_str.split(",")}
```

```
# USAGE
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
print(to_dict("a, b, c"))  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Must be defined in the same file it's used (cannot be `import`ed). See other caveats in comments.

Comment: Instead of using loose individual variables, use some data structure which can be converted into a dict easy to begin with…?

Comment: @deceze Requesting reopen - I've updated my question; I have my own answer to post that answers the intended question.

Comment: Can you clarify what the difference is better? As is I can’t see how those questions differ from yours.

Comment: But really, in a nutshell, there *isn't* a great way to do it in Python. The best possible answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783867/476) from the duplicate. The approach @ibarrond gives below requires your to define the `var_dict` function *in every scope that you want to use it*, which is obviously way more complicated than just repeating the names. If you want a function you can define once and `import` everywhere as needed, you need something like given in the duplicate.

Comment: I'd also argue that giving the function names as strings breaks a lot of static code checkers, since they can't track variable names for you. Some special syntax like Javascript's `{ a, b }` doesn't suffer that problem, but since Python doesn't have that and the best you can do is something like `var_dict('a b')`, you're losing static tooling support, which would be enough reason for me to avoid this entirely.

Comment: @deceze Hmm, yeah, didn't figure it'd fail via `import` - but not too bad since it's a two-liner to redefine (or one lambda). Also fair point on linting. Nonetheless, I have some use cases where this does more good than harm - e.g., in `__main__`, where it's desired to lessen vertical file length, or where "var_list" is pre-validated. This question stands as unique as it's less "demanding" and more narrowed than the others, and there's a unique answer. And for the record, @ibarrond's solution doesn't work for me; I get `{}`, whether importing `compact()` or defining it locally.

Comment: Anyway, my problem's resolved - if the question remains closed, I'll just post my answer in the question for others' reference.

Answer (score -1):

Using `eval`, we can get a dictionary of string representations of all the variables whose names are in a list.

```
def var_dict(var_str): 
    return {i:eval("%s"%i) for i in var_str.split()}
```

We try it out:

```py
a = '1=2'
b = '2'
c = 4
d = [1,2,'3']



var_dict(var_str='a b c d')
#> {'a': '1=2', 'b': '2', 'c': 4, 'd': [1, 2, '3']}
```

There is one **caveat** about this technique: You need to provide a list of variable names as strings `['a','b','c']` and not just `[a,b,c]`. I believe this is not much of an issue since you just want to avoid writing the long variable names multiple times.

---

If you're worried about using `eval`, you can encapsulate the code being run in an `f-string`, thus ensuring that only the existing variables will be executed, and so avoiding code injection:

```
def var_dict(var_str): 
    return {i:eval("f'{%s}"%i) for i in var_str.split()}
var_dict(['a b c d'])
#> {'a': '1=2', 'b': '2', 'c': '4', 'd': "[1, 2, '3']"}

var_dict(['a=1','b','c','d'])  # Would've set a=1 in the previous code
#> ERROR! there is no variable named 'a=1'
```

Note that in this case all returned values are turned into strings (this is the best solution if you are working only with strings or if you were already planning to convert all variables to strings later on).

Comment: That's not equivalent at all.

Comment: Why not? It looks correct (unlike answers in the links); what am I missing?

Comment: @anatolyg Given `foo = 42`, `dict(foo=foo)` creates the dict `{'foo': 42}`. This here code would create `{'foo': 'foo'}`.

Comment: The answers in the links ask for a dict like `var_name=1;  my_func(var_name) #--> {'var_name': 1}`. I thought this question was just asking for `my_func(var_name) #--> {'var_name': 'var_name'}`. But I guess it is the former.

Comment: I think the question was just asking for {'1': '1'}

Comment: @anatolyg Simply test how `dict(a=a)` behaves yourself…?

Comment: @deceze better now?

Comment: Yuck, `eval`!? Also, this won't work if `var_dict` is written in another file and imported, or simply in another scope…

Comment: `eval` might be ugly, but we are just asking him to print a `f-string`. I'd say it is a valid option.

Comment: But why turn every value into a string?!

Comment: About your second remark, I already assume `var_dict` is in a scope where you can get access to all the variables. It is the equivalent of calling the function with the variables themselves instead of their names: if a variable is not available, it cannot be retrieved

Comment: I was using the `f-strings` to safely encapsulate the code to be executed using `eval`, thus rendering it safe. A more direct approach would be to avoid `f-strings` completely. Good question, though! Answer edited.

Comment: Well done, I happened to have figured it out myself - though `var_list` adds inconvenience; edit your answer like so for me to accept: `{i:eval("%s" % i) for i in vars_str.split(", ")}` - now we can just do `var_dict("a, b, c")`.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Since `var_list = vars_str.split(", ")`, there is very little difference between methods. I'll update the solution anyhow.

Comment: The difference is significant in use convenience, which is the main purpose of my question: `['a', 'b', 'c']` vs. `'a, b, c'`.

Comment: Done! now the function accepts `'a b c d'`