# python dictionary out of a list of variables

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Imagine the following code:

```
a = 45
b = 'New York'
c = [1,2,3]
```

A way to make a dict out of it is straight forward:

```
{'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
```

oftentimes when looping through data collection and extracting data you encounter that those variables should be added to a dict (or list of dicts).

Is there any other way to transform [a,b,c] into {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c} in one liner??
what I look for is:

```
mydict = onliner([a,b,c])
```

The truly motivation is to avoid boilerplate writing since the name o the variables are like:

publication_date_in_europe or section_type_code

which makes the writing of the dict cumbersome

```
{'publication_date_in_europe':publication_date_in_europe,
'section_type_code'section_type_code}
```

thanks

edit NOTE 1: this dict is made in real case out of a high number of variables. It is desired to have every of those vars first in a line for easy reading code. Every variable corresponds to accessing a deep nested JSON structure.

edit NOTE 2: Making this question duplicate of other question is fine, but please avoid referring to questions that speak about other languages. I code in python and dont have the intention to read any single PHP code line: [Python equivalent of PHP's compact() and extract()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783781/python-equivalent-of-phps-compact-and-extract).

Comment: Why not avoid introducing variables which should have been keys to a dictionary all along? There is no one-liner which will refactor code.

Comment: The duplicate is exactly what you're looking for. It simply happens to be framed around PHP, since in PHP that functionality exists natively, and the OP of that other questions was searching for an equivalent in Python. **The answers all pertain to Python.** Read them.